# Alternatives to multicast

Tags: java, networking, multicast

I'm currently developing a server (using Java) that has to send quite often (every 10-30 seconds) a few bytes to multiple clients (10 - 100). At first, I thought of using UDP multicast datagrams (java.net.MulticastSocket), but I thought of this not being a good solution because of the bad support for multicast on most routers.

So I'm wondering if it would be a good idea if I sent all data directly to the hosts via unicast or do you know of anything more elegant/with less traffic?

Comment: It's the year 2011. Just thinking about optimizing this costs more than you'll ever spend on the traffic.

Comment: 'Bad support'? Multicast is really well supported on most routers for about the last 20 years, but it does have to be configured. But I agree with Jochen that a few bytes to 100 clients every 20-30 seconds isn't worth worrying about trying to optimize. If you were distributing a movie to ten thousand clients in real time, yes. This, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many advantages in using JMS, but most of these use TCP and so could you.  A few bytes every 10-30 seconds to a few hundred clients is small even on low bandwidth networks.

Say you send a 100 bytes message to 100 clients every 10 seconds, That 1000 bytes per second or 8Kbits/second.  Even 3G networks will support this bandwidth easily. i.e. you could do this with a smart phone. ;)

The simplest approach may be to have a tcp connection from each client which the server sends update messages as required.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a message queue such as [Active MQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)?  These have the nice characteristic that you write the message once to the queue and you can have as many readers as you like reading the queue.

Comment: +1: If you want something like multi-cast, a Topic is a better choice than a Queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [gossip-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol) application-level multicast protocol. For instance, [NeEM](http://neem.sf.net) will scale easily to 100 destinations while providing an interface similar to MulticastSocket and using just TCP/IP, thus being compatible with less than optimal network setups.